# Get content of specific HTML Tag JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the content of specific tag in HTML as a string or as XML

```
<body>
    <script src="jquery.min.js">
    //var test = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    //alert(test[0]);
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var test = $("input");
            alert(test);
        }

    </script>

    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
    <textarea id="TextArea1" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
    <textarea id="TextArea1" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />

    <circuit>
        <c type="Bipolar" name="c1">
            <cathode row="10" col="20" />
            <anode row="15" col="50" />

        </c>
        <and name="and1">
            ``
            <input>
            <pin row="10" col="40"></pin>
            <pin row="20" col="40"></pin>
            </Input>
            <output>
                <pin row="30" col="50"></pin>
            </output>
        </and>

        <diode name="d1" value="30">
            <anode row="30" col="50"></anode>
            <cathode row="40" col="60"></cathode>
        </diode>

        <r type="Constant" name="r1">
            <node row="60" col="80"></node>
            <node row="70" col="80"></node>
        </r>
    </circuit>
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />

    <textarea id="TextArea1" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>

</body>
```

I need only `<Circuit>` tag and all elements inside it like this

```
<Circuit>
<C Type="Bipolar" Name="c1">
        <Cathode row="10" col="20"/>
        <Anode row="15" col="50"/>

    </C>
    <AND Name="and1">``
        <Input>
            <Pin row="10" col="40"></Pin>
            <Pin row="20" col="40"></Pin>
        </Input>
        <Output>
            <Pin row="30" col="50"></Pin>
        </Output>
    </AND>

    <Diode Name="d1" Value="30">
        <Anode row="30" col="50"></Anode>
        <Cathode row="40" col="60"></Cathode>
    </Diode>

<R Type="Constant" Name="r1">
    <Node row="60" col="80"></Node>
    <Node row="70" col="80"></Node>
</R>    
</Circuit>
```

I'm trying to get this tag by using JQuery, DOM but can't

```
<script src="jquery.min.js">
        $(Document).ready(function ()
        {
           var test = $("circuit").children(0).html;
           alert(test);
        }
        );

</script>
```

Also Dom :

```
var test = document.getElementsByTagName("circuit")
```

We can't put circuit tag in `div` and give `div` id , class name , and also circuit tag.

Is there another solution?

Comment: you don't NEED or CAN'T?

Comment: Do you need to have the `circuit` tags included?

Answer (score 2):

I think I got what you want.

1) If you need the "circuit" tags included, then there's no other way other than virtually prepend a tag and get from that, like this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/86bDY/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   var test = $("<div>").prepend($("circuit"));
   alert(test.html());
 });
```

2) If you don't need the "Circuit" tags, just run like the other answers:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   var test = $("circuit"));
   alert(test.html());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

html() is a jQuery method, so you'll have to use the brackets :

```
    //document not Document
    $(document).ready(function (){
       var test = $("circuit").html();
       console.log(test);
    });
```

Comment: i think he needs them in capital case

Comment: @blackbee: HTML is case insensitive, so it doesn't matter. But even if it would, the OP posted two different pieces of HTML. I'm sure it's not asking too much of the OP to adjust the casing if they need to.

Comment: i know that. maybe he doesnot. I mean he wrote getElementsByTagName('circuit'); but then he also says he cannot achieve what he needs. Today is s confusing.

Comment: the last answer doesn't give me what i need , no output occurred

Comment: @EmanAli `console.log()` will produce an output in the console of the web inspector tool of your browser (i.e. Firebug...), but you can use `alert()` if you prefer

Comment: I know this point Eng @Oliboy50 , i already used alert but no alerts occurred

Answer (score 0):

You can't write script tags like this. It makes no sense.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js">
    $(Document).ready(function ()
    {
       var test = $("circuit").children(0).html;
       alert(test);
    }
    );

</script>
```

Do this instead.

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        //stuff to run on load
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your help , the last answer return so strange o/p "function (a){return V(this,function(a){var b=this[0]||{},c=0,d=this.length;if(void 0===a)return 1===b.nodeType?b.innerHTML.replace(fb,""):void 0;if(!("string"!=typeof a||mb.test(a)||!k.htmlSerialize&&gb.test(a)||!k.leadingWhitespace&&hb.test(a)||rb[(jb.exec(a)||["",""])[1].toLowerCase()])){a=a.replace(ib,"<$1></$2>");try{for(;d>c;c++)b=this[c]||{},1===b.nodeType&&(m.cleanData(ub(b,!1)),b.innerHTML=a);b=0}catch(e){}}b&&this.empty().append(a)},null,a,arguments.length)}"

Answer (score -1):

```
var test = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].innerHTML;
alert(test);
```

Comment: well input[0] doesn't have text inside its node... if you are trying to get a textbox value you could use textbox.value

Comment: You should explain what your code is doing. The answer should not only contain copy-paste data.